# How to listen to dom ready event in angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, events, angularjs-ng-include

This is my example

http://plnkr.co/edit/Foc5vEa5HJ0Uz1fGZXtS?p=preview

css:

```
.header{
  background:#f00;
  height: 40px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
html,body{
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
}
.footer{
  background:#00f;
  height:40px;
}
.main{
  padding-top:40px;
  min-height:calc(100% - 80px);
}
.main-section{
  height:100%;
  background:#fF0;
}
.fit-parent-height{
  height:100%;
}
```

html:

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div class="header">HEADER</div>
    <div class="main" fit-parent-height> 
      <div class="main-section" ng-include="'main-section.html'" ></div>
      <div class="footer">FOOTER</div>  
    </div>
  </body>
```

js:

```
scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded',function(e){
     //add class to change min-height to height in css;
})
```

I want to make main-section block height fit parent
but it not work....

I try to bind $viewContentLoaded, $stateChangeSuccess, $includeContentLoaded, but still not work.

Please help me, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is totally right. And It is failing at `el.outerHeight()` function. The reason behind it is Angular internally uses lighter version of jQuery ehich is nothing but `jqLite` API & In [**jqLite API**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) doesn't contain the [`outerHeight()`](http://api.jquery.com/outerheight/) method.

You need to include [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) file inside your Plunkr will work fine

**EDIT**(Changes per update in question)

As you mention in your question functionality of all three events is given below.

> **$includeContentRequested** 
>   Emitted every time the ngInclude content is requested
>   **$viewContentLoaded** Emitted every time the ngView content is reloaded.
>   **$stateChangeSuccess** Called when hash url change occurs

All of above three don't tell us that view is rendered on UI or not.

Remove all events like `$viewContentLoaded` and all.
Then add `ng-init="switchFitParent()"` on the div of your inner `ng-include="'test.html'"`

`ng-init` will call on rendering of that div which contains `ng-include` direcitve and then the method of `switchFitParent()` method will set/remove class.

**main-section.html**

```
<div>
  <style>
    h3{margin:0};
  </style>
  <h3>MAIN SECTION</h3>
  <div ng-include="'test.html'" ng-init="switchFitParent()"></div>
</div>
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/sd2xvWss5T5CD72HFDVb?p=preview)

Hope this could help you. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I forgot to include jquery lib in [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Foc5vEa5HJ0Uz1fGZXtS?p=preview). I update my code in plunker. I think my problem is how to do some stuff after dom ready when I have two level ng-include. Thank you again.

Comment: @miterfrants Answer added please check.does it working as expected?

Comment: @pankajpakar Thank you again.
If I have a lot of ng-include I have to add ng-init every where right?
No lazy solution for it?

Comment: yeah..in your case It is..but there may be the case sometimes, you may need to use `$timeout(function(){//your code});` $timeout gets call exactly next to the current digest cycle completion